# How to restrict dragging in Smart GWT?

Tags: javascript, gwt, drag-and-drop, drag, smartgwt

I was trying to dragging a canvas within a canvas. To handle the dragging events I was using

> `addDragRepositionStartHandler`,
>   `addDragRepositionMoveHandler`,`addDragRepositionStopHandler`

handlers.

I need to restrict dragging on few condition. Lets say I want to restrict dragging when we'll get `event.getX()` more than 500 in `public void onDragRepositionMove(DragRepositionMoveEvent event)`.

I tried `event.cancel();`, but it don't serve the purpose. All I need is to restrict the dragging.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#effects_dd_tracker) showcase demo. Some relevant code extracted from the demo:

```
    DragPiece green = new DragPiece("pawn_green.png"){  
        @Override  
        protected boolean setDragTracker() {  
            String html = Canvas.imgHTML("pieces/24/pawn_green.png", 24, 24);  
            EventHandler.setDragTracker(html);  
            return false;  
        }  
    };  
    green.setID("greenPiece");  
    green.setTitle("Green Piece");  
    green.setLeft(150);  
    green.setTop(50);  


    final Label label = new Label("Drop Here");  
    label.setLeft(250);  
    label.setTop(50);  
    label.setShowEdges(true);  
    label.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);  
    label.setCanAcceptDrop(true);  
    label.addDropOverHandler(new DropOverHandler() {  
        public void onDropOver(DropOverEvent event) {  
            label.setBackgroundColor("#FFFF88");              
        }  
    });  

    label.addDropOutHandler(new DropOutHandler() {  
        public void onDropOut(DropOutEvent event) {  
            label.setBackgroundColor("#ffffff");  
        }             
    });  

    label.addDropHandler(new DropHandler() {  
        public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {  
            Canvas target = EventHandler.getDragTarget();  
            SC.say("You dropped the " +  target.getID());                 
        }             
    });
```

Some notes about this code:

1. Notice how a label is used to define the drop region, but you could use other `Canvas` objects for that purpose.
2. The `addDropOverHandler`, `addDropOutHandler` and `addDropHandler` methods allow you to add the required handlers to this `Label` or `Canvas` object to produce the desired results.
3. `DragPiece` is just a subclass of Img that has `setCanDragReposition(true)` and `setCanDrop(true)`, so that the element is draggable.